# Spring Boot - infinite loop service

Tags: java, service, spring-boot, infinite-loop, headless

I want to build a headless application which will query the DB in infinite loop and perform some operations in certain conditions (e.g. fetch records with specific values and when found launch e-mail sending procedure for each message).

I want to use Spring Boot as a base (especially because of Actuator to allow expose health-checks), but for now I used Spring Boot for building REST web-services.

Is there any best practices or patterns to follow when building infinite loop applications ? Does anyone tried to build it based on Spring Boot and can share with me his architecture for this case ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'm using is a message broker and a consumer put at the spring boot application to do the job.

Comment: You mean that you use Spring Integration to create channel to poll database and then when something is found your consumer is executing a logic on found rows ?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I finally used Spring Integration + Spring Boot. I used JDBC Inbound Channel Adapter to pool database and written my own ServiceActivator to react on found rows. Work like a charm with a little amount of code.

Answer (score 26):

Do not implement an infinite loop yourself. Let the framework handle it using its [task execution](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) capabilities:

```
@Service
public class RecordChecker{

    //Executes each 500 ms
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=500)
    public void checkRecords() {
        //Check states and send mails
    }
}
```

Don't forget to enable scheduling for your application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Is it possible to use a similar construct where you can use a variable for (or instead of) 'fixedRate'? For example I want to read the value vor 'fixedRate' from a configuration file. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281633/spring-boot-infinite-loop-with-configurable-cycle-time)

Answer (score 3):

There are several options. My approach is to start a loop on an ApplicationReadyEvent, and abstract away the loop logic into an injectable service. In my case it was a game loop, but this pattern should work for you as well.

```java
package com.ryanp102694.gameserver;

import com.ryanp102694.gameserver.service.GameProcessor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GameLauncher implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameLauncher.class);

    private GameProcessor gameProcessor;

    @Autowired
    public GameLauncher(GameProcessor gameProcessor){
        this.gameProcessor = gameProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        logger.info("Starting game process.");
        gameProcessor.start();
        while(gameProcessor.isRunning()){
            logger.debug("Collecting user input.");
            gameProcessor.collectInput();
            logger.debug("Calculating next game state.");
            gameProcessor.nextGameState();
            logger.debug("Updating clients.");
            gameProcessor.updateClients();
        }
        logger.info("Stopping game process.");
        gameProcessor.stop();
    }
}
```