# Spring Boot: Infinite loop with configurable cycle time

Tags: java, spring-boot, infinite-loop

I have a spring boot application that runs indefinitely as a service, cycling through its tasks every x seconds. This cycle time comes from a configuration file and can change at runtime. I used a self-made infinite while loop for that:

```
@Component
public class MainCycle implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            ...
            waitCycleTime()
        }
    }

}
```

I have read that you shouldn't implement your own infinite loops when using Spring Boot ([Spring Boot - infinite loop service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541857/spring-boot-infinite-loop-service)), but if I used Spring's `@Scheduled(fixedRate=500)` annotation, I'd have to use a compile time constant for the cycle time.

What is the best way to implement an infinite loop with a cycle time that can change during runtime when using Spring Boot?

Comment: An alternative way could be to use scheduling-tasks, there is an example available here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: @Greg I know this example. It uses the @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000) annotation which I mentioned in my question. It uses a compile time constant, but I need a value that can change at runtime.